# My Laptop sometimes cannot connect to Internet while using WiFi

Tags: wireless, 15.04, internet

When I'm using WiFi on laptop with Ubuntu 15.04 regularly (30 percent of all connections) can not connect to Internet and shows errors "err_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED".
My Wireless Device is Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter.
Calling lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 command, outputs:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2c97]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

How to solve this problem?

@waltinator says "Please edit your question" means to add the results here, in the Question, where it can be formatted for readability, like this:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2c97]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k.
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` from the terminal.

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2c97]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k

Comment: Check wifi setting. I had same issue due to short preamble setting. Try to use long preamble.